# Can I get the real width & height of a Text element?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, plasmoid

I would like to get the real width & height of a `Text` element. If I use the `paintedWidth` & `paintedHeight` properties, I don't get it. For example:

```
Rectangle {
    color:  "green"
    width:  a_text.paintedWidth
    height: a_text.paintedHeight

    Text {
        id:     a_text
        text:   "r"
        color:  "white"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

If I run that code, I see some green space on the left of the `"r"` on top of the `"r"` and below the `"r"`. So I'm not getting the real width & height of the `Text`. I mean, the width & height of the white pixels.

Any way to do it?

P.S. Also I would need the relative position of the real top-left corner of the text, I mean, the x & y of the top-left white pixel relative to the "official" top-left pixel of the `Text`.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your issues

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to use the new `TextMetrics` element (requires QtQuick 2.5), and its `tightBoundingRect` property, to get the real `width` & `heigth` of the foreground text:

```
import QtQuick 2.5      // required!

Rectangle {
    color:  "green"
    width:  t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.width
    height: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height

    Text {
        id:     a_text
        text:   "r"
        color:  "white"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    TextMetrics {
        id:     t_metrics
        font:   a_text.font
        text:   a_text.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This didn't show any text for me. Had to add `anchors.fill: parent` to the Text component.

Answer (score 3):

"your_text_object.paintedHeight" or "your_text_object.paintedWidth": is what you need to get the height of the text, including height past the height which is covered due to there being more text than fits in the set height.

[Text QML Element paintedHeight](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop)

Comment: This link is broken and leads to outdated documentation of version 4.8. Current Qt 5 [Text Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) doesn't have such properties. They work though, perhaps for the sake of compatibility. But who knows how long?

Comment: The link is updated now

Comment: @AdrianoCampos the links lead to Image.paintedHeight. Still not relevant